# pandas, split, or divide(subtract) dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, split, divide

I have a dataframe "moment_f". 
and i have to delete some rows from moment_f that contains the name "AH".
However I shall not delete every "AH" rows so I made a new dataframe that
contains the "AH" that I want to delete.

```
ah1 = moment_f[moment_f["TextGridLabel"] == "AH"]
ah_d = ah1.iloc[::2] 
# got the odd rows of "AH" which is what I need to get rid of from the original dataframe "moment_f".
```

so now I want to delete dataframe"ah_d" from dataframe "moment_f".

What would be the opposite of concatenation? 
I've tried drop, split, etc but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC need:

```
df = moment_f[~moment_f.index.isin(ah_d.index)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid creating a "subset dataframe" by working *only* with indices. This is possible with `iloc` but not trivial. Importantly, the below solution works only with integer positional location, not index labels, i.e. it does not assume unique indices.

```
import numpy as np

# some example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3]})

# extract indices to remove
idx = np.where(df['A'] == 1)[0][::2]  # array([0, 4, 7], dtype=int64)

# include all indices which do not match idx
res = df.iloc[~np.in1d(np.arange(df['A'].shape[0]), idx)]

print(res)

   A
1  2
2  3
3  1
5  2
6  1
8  1
9  3
```

If your index is the regular `pd.RangeIndex`, i.e. `0, 1, ..., n`, you can drop by label via [`pd.DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
res = df.drop(idx, axis='rows')
```